# got error 203(ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND) when calling CreateEnvironmentBlock()

Tags: windows, winapi

env.c:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Userenv.h>
#include <Wtsapi32.h>
int main() {
    DWORD err;
    HANDLE hTokenThis = NULL;
    HANDLE hTokenDup = NULL;
    HANDLE hThisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    OpenProcessToken(hThisProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hTokenThis);

    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err002:%d\n",err);

    LPVOID pEnv = NULL;
    CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv, hTokenThis, TRUE);

    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err003:%d\n",err);
    return 0;
}
```

compile and run in the cmd.exe of the current local desktop:

```
gcc -o env.exe env.c -lUserenv
env.exe
err002:126
err003:203
```

OS is win7 and gcc is 4.5.2 from mingw.

I am so confused that why it got error 203.

Comment: You call `GetEnvironmentBlock`, but you don't check the return value. Are you sure the call actually failed?

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to the return value of winapi functions.  Only call GetLastError() when they return a failure code.

The token you pass to CreateEnvironmentBlock() must be a user token, one you obtain by calling LogonUser().

Comment: What do you mean by "user token"?

Comment: A token that represents a user.  Check the LogonUser docs, last argument.

Comment: Well I was wondering what you meant by "user token" as opposed to ... some other kind of token without a user?